# the type or namespace name 'Student' could not be found

Tags: c#

I am completely new to C# and need to convert a small java application to C# but can't seem to get it to compile.

I have my Student class which looks like this:

```
using System;

public class Student
{

    private string name;
    private string userName;
    private double gpa;

    public Student()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.userName = "";
        this.gpa = 0;
    }

    public Student(string nameIn, string userNameIn, double gpaIn)
    {
        this.name = nameIn;
        this.userName = userNameIn;
        this.gpa = gpaIn;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double GetGPA()
    {
        return this.gpa;
    }

    public string GetEmail()
    {
        string email = this.userName + "@ksu.edu";

        return email;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = this.name + "\n" + GetEmail() + "\n" + "GPA: " + this.gpa;

        return str;
    }

} // end class
```

And I have my app class that I *attempt* to instantiate this object in, i.e:

```
Student student = new Student(name, userName, gpa);
```

But, when I try to compile it, it gives me the error:

> Lab11.cs(79,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Student' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The line that is throwing ther error is where I try to instantiate the object, the only lines written before it in that class are just to get the name, username, and gpa values.

Comment: Have you checked the solutions the error gives you? Particularly the "using directive" bit.

Comment: I've changed your title to reflect your actual error. The error suggested by the original title would have had a very different cause.

Comment: In the "app class" where you try to instantiate, does Visual Studio give you red squigglies under `Student`? If so, place your cursor there and hit Ctrl+. , tell us what happens.

Comment: No, no red squiggly, it just shows as plain white text

Comment: Also, I don't know what 'using' directive I would need. Would I need to have one for the Student class?

Comment: In general I recommend including in your code example the line of code that is actually causing the error. All you've included is the class implementation, which does not tell us what the problem might be.

Comment: @JohnWu In fact, it may. There is no `namespace MyApplication { ... `. Conhair: Do you have a `namespace` in your Student.cs ?

Comment: No, I didn't think I needed one, I will try to add one.

Comment: You don't need the namespace, but you do need to make sure both files are added to your project.  If in doubt, type: `Student student = new Student()` put your text cursor on `Student` and press `ctrl+.` and choose `Generate class 'Student' in new file` and it will set up the class for you.  Then you can copy and paste the guts over to where it created it.

Comment: @Wyck Totally missed, the file could _not_ be part of the project. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Try add namespace in your student class file

```
namespace NameYourProject.NameYourFolder.Student
{
  public class Student
  {
   ...your code
  }
}
```